# Create Shortcode for Slick Slider & ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater, slick.js

I am building a WP site and would like to insert a slider I've started building with Slick Slider as a shortcode.

I have created custom fields (a repeater with an image, three text inputs, and a page link) and I have them only showing on my home page. My ideal workflow would be that the client only edits this block of fields on the homepage to add and remove slides, while a shortcode placed in the page builder would render it.

***Is this possible?***

I'd prefer not to make a CPT just to get the slides on the homepage, but I can if that's the route this should go. I'm currently creating the template file that has the individual slide mark-up and the loops to pull the fields, but can share if that is helpful. I really just need help with how to create the shortcode... I didn't understand the page I read in the WordPress documentation.

Comment: Hi you can place this code in your functions.php just edit path to you file [my-slider] will be your short code function slider_main() {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part('path/to/file'); 
    return ob_get_clean();   
} 
add_shortcode( 'my-slider', 'slider_main' );

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable. When creating the shortcode functionality just refer to the homepage id.

```
function gallery_shortcode(){
  $pageID = get_option('page_on_front');
  if(get_field('slider',$pageID):
    $content = "<div id="slider">;
    while(have_rows('slider', $pageID): the_row();
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image(get_sub_field('image'),'full');
      $content = '<div class="single-slide">';
      $content = $image;
      $content = '<p>'.get_sub_field("text_link").'</p>';
      $content = '</div>';
    endwhile;
    $content = "</div>";
  endif;
return $content;
}
add_shortcode("gallery","gallery_shortcode");
```